# Using a form on a knockout.js template

Tags: forms, templates, input, knockout.js

I have a knockout template that is successfully receiving data. I added a form to the template with a text input and a submit input and bound an observable view model property within the text input.

When bind the text input value to the view model property ( the incoming data is lost and the button doesn't work. I'm dumping the incoming data before and after the input tag and the data is gone on the second dump.

Following is the template code snippet:

```
<div class="container">
    <div style="width:100%;">
        <div class="panel panel-primary" style="max-width:700px; margin:0 auto;">
            <div class="panel panel-heading" style="text-align:right">
                <a href="/Authentication/Logout" style="text-decoration:none; color:white"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Logout</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-bind="foreach: tabs">
                <li data-bind="css: { active: isSelected }">
                    <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.selectedTab"><span data-bind="html: name" /> </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" data-bind="template: { name: getTemplate, data: getTemplateData }"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script id="0" type="text/html">
    <br />

    <div class="row" style="margin-left:1px; margin-right:5px; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px;">

        <form>
            <div>
                <pre data-bind="text: JSON.stringify(ko.toJS($data), null, 2)"></pre>
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: $parent.cameraName,  valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" placeholder="New Camera Name..." />
                <pre data-bind="text: JSON.stringify(ko.toJS($data), null, 2)"></pre>
                <input type="submit" data-bind="click: $parent.addCamera" value="ADD" />
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>

    <div data-bind="foreach: $data">
        <div class="rounded-radius-5">
            Name: <span class="spaces" data-bind="text: name"></span> |
            <span class="spaces"></span>
            Job: <span class="spaces" data-bind="text: job"></span> |
            <span class="spaces"></span>
            Status: <span data-bind="style: { color: textColor }"><span class="spaces" data-bind="text: status"></span></span> 
            <div style="text-align:right; float: right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></div>
        </div>
    </div>


</script>
```

Following is the json dump:

```
[
  {
    "cameraid": 1,
    "name": "WS-LICAM01",
    "job": "100",
    "status": "CheckedOut",
    "textColor": "#FF0000"
  },
  {
    "cameraid": 2,
    "name": "WS-LICAM02",
    "job": "916",
    "status": "CheckedOut",
    "textColor": "#FF0000"
  },
  {
    "cameraid": 3,
    "name": "WS-LICAM03",
    "job": "956",
    "status": "CheckedOut",
    "textColor": "#FF0000"
  },
  {
    "cameraid": 4,
    "name": "WS-LICAM04",
    "job": "956",
    "status": "CheckedOut",
    "textColor": "#FF0000"
  },
  {
    "cameraid": 5,
    "name": "WS-LICAM05",
    "job": "9999",
    "status": "CheckedOut",
    "textColor": "#FF0000"
  }
]
```

Can anyone help with this issue or let me know a better way?

Comment: Could you show the viewmodel as well?

Comment: In the `ADD` button  you are mixing submit with click.  If the div with the foreach was inside the form, and the binding of the `ADD` button was `submit`, then all your data will be submited.  Please, look at this link:  http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/submit-binding.html.  Hope this helps.

Comment: The above is an incomplete form. I was just using the snippet to show how the data goes missing when you use data-bind in the text input

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found an ugly way of submitting the form without trashing my incoming data.

Here is my new form:

```
<script id="0" type="text/html">
    <div class="row" style="margin-left:1px; margin-right:5px; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px;">
        <form data-bind="submit: $parent.addCamera">
            <input type="text" name="tbxCamera" id="tbxCamera" placeholder="New Camera Name..." />
            <button type="submit">ADD</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div><p><h4>Checked Out</h4></p></div>
    <div style="overflow-y:scroll; height:auto; max-height:160px;">
        <div data-bind="foreach: $data">
            <!-- ko if: checkedOut -->
            <div class="rounded-radius-5">
                Name: <span class="spaces" data-bind="text: name"></span> |
                <span class="spaces"></span>
                Job: <span class="spaces" data-bind="text: job"></span> |
                <span class="spaces"></span>
                Status: <span data-bind="style: { color: textColor }"><span class="spaces" data-bind="text: status"></span></span>
                <div style="text-align:right; float: right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></div>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div><p><h4>Checked In</h4></p></div>
    <div style="overflow-y:scroll; height:auto; max-height:160px;">
        <div data-bind="foreach: $data">
            <!-- ko ifnot: checkedOut -->
            <div class="rounded-radius-5">
                Name: <span class="spaces" data-bind="text: name"></span> |
                <span class="spaces"></span>
                Job: <span class="spaces" data-bind="text: job"></span> |
                <span class="spaces"></span>
                Status: <span data-bind="style: { color: textColor }"><span class="spaces" data-bind="text: status"></span></span>
                <div style="text-align:right; float: right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></div>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

The value from the form is extracted in my ViewModel as follows:

NOTE: data[0] is the text input and data[1] is the button. I'm only using the text input

```
self.addCamera = function (data, event) {
    var newCamera = [{
        CameraId: 6,
        Name: data[0].value,
        Job: 'N/A',
        Status: 'CheckedIn'
    }];

    self.cameras($.map(newCamera, function (item) {
        return new camera(item);
    }));
};
```

Comment: I just edited my answer. For some reason it won't show just the form part, so I added the entire template